# Solve the recursion $a_n=\frac{1}{4}2^{n-1}-1+3a_{n-1}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the recursion $a_n=\frac{1}{4}2^{n-1}-1+3a_{n-1}$

I'd know how to solve it if it weren't for that -1. Because of it, I can't divide the particular equation with $2^{n-2}$ to solve it. What can be done here?

Oh, sorry. The starting conditions are $a_3=1$, and by "solve" I mean, find the explicit for of $a_n$ (the non recursive one)

Comment: what do you mean by solve?

Comment: What is the start condition? I mean, the value of $x_0$?

Comment: Please read my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*:

Consider $b_n=a_n-\frac{1}{2}$

Can you write a recursive equation for $b_n$?

Comment: Hey! That works! Thanks for giving me a hint

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$a_{n} - 1/2 = 2^{n - 1}/4 + 3\pars{a_{n -1} - 1/2}$. Set
$a_{n} - 1/2 = 2^{n - 1}b_{n}/4\quad\iff\quad b_{n} = 2^{3 - n}\pars{a_{n} - 1/2}$
with $b_{3} = 1/2$.
$$
{1 \over 4}\,2^{n - 1}b_{n} = {1 \over 4}\,2^{n - 1}
+
3\,{1 \over 4}\,2^{n -2}b_{n - 1}\quad\imp\quad
b_{n} = 1 + {3 \over 2}\,b_{n - 1}
$$
$$
b_{n} + 2 = {3 \over 2}\pars{b_{n - 1} + 2}
= \pars{3 \over 2}^{2}\pars{b_{n - 2} + 2} = \cdots =
\pars{3 \over 2}^{n - 3}\bracks{b_{n - \pars{n - 3}} + 2}
$$
$$
a_{n} = \half + 2^{n - 3}b_{n}
= \half + 2^{n - 3}\bracks{-2 + \pars{3 \over 2}^{n - 3}\,{5 \over 2}}
= \half - 2^{n - 2}+ {5 \over 2}\,3^{n - 3}
$$
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
a_{n} = \half - 2^{n - 2}+ {5 \over 2}\,3^{n - 3}
}
$$